# Google reCAPTCHA not showing up in my heroku app

Tags: heroku, sails.js, recaptcha

Google reCAPTCHA  is working fine as expected locally but not at heroku.

The herokuapp has a custom domain however.

Not sure but could be a problem with adding the site with reCAPTCHA. https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

I tried - 
mysite.com
mysite.herokuapp.com

Not luck!

Looking at the source code, in my heroku app, i see the dom loaded with the markup for reCAPTCHA but not showing up. Can't validate the form and submit.

Please suggest me on this or i should i go for add two number validation.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see errors or warnings in your client console?

Comment: Thanks for responding, Meeker. I was working on it few weeks back and eventually had to implement own logic for random number and add two numbers challenge. I can't say for sure if I saw any errors. I thought Google also changes it's api implementation so I was cool with custom logic.